# CSS responsive navigation, how to add "full" covered background in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, navigation, customization

I've found this great responsive CSS Navigation: [Navigation at codepen](https://codepen.io/mutedblues/pen/MmPNPG)

how can i add a fully background only in mobile view? i tried to style the **"ul-element"** but it doesn't work.

```
.header .menu {
   background-color:red;
}
```

it should like this:

[image: example navigation]

the "X" icon is ok, i only need a full background. i tried to add a "div-element" between header and the menu-part. but this also not work.

any idea? how i can add this, without "bigger changes", the navigation is "perfect" for me. i favourite small and clean solutions.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Working Demo**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.header .logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .header li {
    float: left;
  }
  .header li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .header .menu {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .header .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 48em) {
  body,.header .menu{background:#2f66fe;}
  .header li a {border-right:none;}
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">CSS Nav</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn">
    <span class="navicon"></span>
  </label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Our Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you want background in mobile view to header completely. if the backgroudn nedd while menu button  clicked only?

Comment: only in mobile view the background fill out the full page. the main color of the navigation do not touch this.

Comment: Is this like. if any changes comment me

Comment: Are you want change  menu color ?

Comment: hi, thanks for your input. but if you add a simple div or p tag, content "lorem ipsum", then the mobile menu background  will break. i think we have to add a outer menu container ... the part after links should also filled out with background color.

Answer (score 0):

[see image of working code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHRuh.png)Use after or before property to give the complete background in media query. There is some parent div. You can make it relative and then

```
div:after {
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   left: 0;
   right:0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   background: blue;
}
```

After this make the z-index of nav elements greater else they won't be clickable.

Comment: It worked for me. See I have attached the screenshot as well.